# How can I only allow administrators to run my Discord slash command?

Tags: python, discord.py

Question 1. How can I make it so that only an administrator can use a specific slash command?

This is an example of one of my current slash commands:

```
@client.tree.command(name="8ball", description = "gives an 8-ball style answer to any question")
@app_commands.describe(thing_to_say = "question?")
async def _8ball(interaction: discord.Interaction, thing_to_say: str):
    responces = [
        'It is certain', 'It is decidedly so', 'Without a doubt',
        'Yes definitely', 'You may rely on it', 'As I see it, yes',
        'Most likely', 'Outlook good', 'Yes', 'Signs point to yes',
        'Reply hazy, try again', 'Ask again later', 'Better not tell you now',
        'Cannot predict now', 'Concentrate and ask again', 'Dont count on it',
        'My reply is no', 'My sources say no', 'Outlook not so good',
        'Very doubtful'
    ]
    await interaction.response.send_message(f'Question: {thing_to_say}\nAnswer:   {random.choice(responces)}')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To only allow administrators to run your slash commands is really simple. You have two options.

The first option would be you add a decorator over your command function:

```py
@app_commands.checks.has_permissions(administrator=True)
```

And the second option (in my opinion the better one) just with an *if* check:

```py
if not interaction.user.guild_permissions.administrator:
   return await interaction.response.send_message("You have no admin")
```

---

- (first option): *[@discord.app_commands.checks.has_permissions(**perms)](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interactions/api.html?highlight=default_permission#discord.app_commands.checks.has_permissions)*
- (second option): *[property guild_permissions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=guild_permissions#discord.Member.guild_permissions)*